# Getting the fcm token from android app running in appium test

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, appium

I am testing an app using firebase push notifications using appium.

Now I want to send a test notification to the app. For this I need the fcm token from the app.

The app is a production build, it does not display or expose the fcm token anywhere, why should it?

But of course I need to access the token from my appium tests. Is there a good way to extract data normally not exposed using adb? Or some other mechanism on how to get the fcm token without displaying it on a label in the app?

Comment: you can use Firebase Database to update token there....

Comment: You mean my app could write to the firebase database? I would rather not modify the app in such a way when I do not need it for the production environment

Answer (score 1):

Appium itself is actually [using **adb**](https://github.com/appium/appium-adb) to get data related to the app.

If you cannot get fcm token via adb (for security reasons its shouldn't be possible), there is no way Appium can get it.

You may look into Firebase API to check if you can get token from service side. Still the best option will be to use test build where you modified app to expose token.